# Strange clipboard entry added whenever something is copied

Tags: kubuntu, kde, clipboard

Whenever I copy text to the clipboard, a strange entry is added after the text I copied. Here I copied the word "Print", this is what the clipboard history look like afterwards:

[image: strange clipboard entry]

If I try to paste the copied word, nothing happens. When I delete the strange entry (the file icon with the question mark), sometimes it instantly reappears, but usually stays deleted after a few tries. Then I can paste what I intended to copy.

I'm running an up-to-date Kubuntu 20.04. (KDE Plasma 5.18.5, KDE Framework 5.68.0, Qt 5.12.8, Kernel 5.4.0-77-generic) This behavior started a few weeks ago.

Is this a known bug? Is there a fix or a workaround?